# Alternate battery switching module

Tags: diodes, switches, relay

I am looking for an circuit that can do as follows. 
I have DC24v (200A) x2 battery packs and 24v DC electrical equipments..(which uses about 80A atleast) 
So lets say i want a circuit board that can connect 2 battery input and 1 output.
So if i disconnect 1 battery pack the unit should automatically switch to the next battery pack without power interruption.. 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find a relay that rated 24 V/80 A (or higher current) and then wiring should be like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv8kP2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When V1 is connected it will energize the relay and your "equipment" get its power from V1 and when disconnected relay will switch to V2.

You probably have some capacitors at the power outputs which will prevent the relay millisecond connect/disconnect delay interrupt the power.

Comment: Where can i get a relay like this?. Or is there any switch that meets my requirements available for sale?

Comment: Search here: https://uk.farnell.com/c/switches-relays/relays/power-relays